# Create view using PDO fails

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, mariadb

I define my PDO as follows

```
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=db1", $user, $pass);
```

Then I try to create a view in db1

```
    $query = "CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
       select option_name,option_value from db1.options 
      UNION ALL 
       select option_name,option_value from db2.options;"

    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $pdo->exec($query);
    $result = $pdo->commit();
    if ($result) {
        print_r("COMMIT OK!");
    } else {
        print_r("COMMIT FALSE");
        $pdo->rollBack();
    }
```

I get "COMMIT OK" as output but going to the database I see no view at all.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try    `$query = "CREATE VIEW my_view AS (
       select option_name,option_value from db1.options 
      UNION ALL 
       select option_name,option_value from db2.options )"`  instead.

Comment: @RaymondNijland doesn't work.

Comment: ___Small Note___ DDL command execute a Commit by default and you cannot stop that commit. So your commits are unnecessary. Because of this automatic commit becareful where you run DDL as it will also commit anything else you may have `In Flight` Oh that is when you get the DDL Syntax correct of course!

Comment: "I get "COMMIT OK" as output but going to the database I see no view at all. " How did you verify? i mean what MySQL admin program are you using?

Comment: Raymond - in PDO I get this when I do select "Table 'NxAzwWswQf1Aw71r.testme' doesn't exist (SQLSTATE=42S02, CODE=1146)." - I use workbench, also terminal, nothing works.

Comment: To add to @RiggsFolly 's comment -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: even without the commit- just exec($sql) it doesn't work.

Comment: the server is MariaDB tho

Comment: Then I have to ask why you added the mysql tag?

Comment: What version of mariaDB

Comment: @RiggsFolly 10.1.19-MariaDB - it works from normal mysql terminal but not from PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors after calling exec.

Add parentheses around each `SELECT` clause.  (Not necessary except when you have `ORDER BY` etc.)

Toss the transaction code.  (See Comments.)

Do you have permissions to read both db1 and db2?

Did you check for the view this way?

```
USE db1;
SHOW CREATE VIEW my_view;
```

If you checked some other way, please elaborate.